# Which firstname field is always returned in request to Linkedin V2 API?

Tags: linkedin-api

When I request user details from LinkedIn’s V2 People endpoint I get the below:

Which first name and last name attribute can I use to save the user details? Is localizedLastName always returned?

```
{
    "localizedLastName": "abc",
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "abc"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "abc"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5103AQGrCbjMGgxnzQ"
    },
    "id": "226262627",
    "localizedFirstName": "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use this to receive  the first name and last name

$profile['firstName']=array_pop($array['firstName']['localized']);

$profile['lastName']=array_pop($array['lastName']['localized']);